# Opening a popup in a flutter Flutter when onBackgroundMessage gets executed

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the flutter onBackgroundMessage, that gets triggered when the device receives a Firebase Cloud Messaging data message; i should open a popup, but in this event handler I have no `context` object. What's the correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: I created the Listener inside the initState from my HomePage. So when it's executed, my build method will be already called, so the context will exist.. it's working for me. Where are you calling your listener?

Comment: The listener is defined in the `configure` method for my firebase cloud messaging object; by default it does not receive the context. Also, to my understanding the handler must be `static` or `global` object, whose signature is:


    static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) async {...}


So i don't really understand how to pass the context. Also, isn't it that maybe i have in some way to "start" the application, that is clearly stopped, since we are talking about background messages ?

Comment: How about creating a BLOC for these background notifications and subscribe from the Widget? Open Popup when there are new events from BLOC.

Answer (score 1):

I created a class with static methods:

```
class FirebaseMessagingHandler {
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final _bloc = AppModule.to.getBloc<FirebaseMessagingHandlerBloc>();

  void setListeners() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) _iOSPermission();

    getToken();

    refreshToken();
  }

  void getToken() {
    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      _bloc.saveToken(token);
      print('DeviceToken = $token');
    });
  }

  void _iOSPermission() {
    firebaseMessaging.configure();
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
    });
  }

  void refreshToken() {
    firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) {
      _bloc.refreshToken(token);
    });
  }

  void showDialog(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      // data
  }

  void showErrorDialog(BuildContext context, dynamic error) {
      // data
  }

  void redirectToPage(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    // data
  }
}
```

And in my homePage (a page that will always be called when open my app) I call the configure:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _fcm = FirebaseMessagingHandler();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseCloudMessagingListeners();
  }

  void firebaseCloudMessagingListeners() {
    _fcm.firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        try {
          _fcm.showDialog(context, message);
        } catch (e) {
          _fcm.showErrorDialog(context, e);
        }
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        try {
          _fcm.redirectToPage(context, message);
        } catch (e) {
          _fcm.showErrorDialog(context, e);
        }
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        try {
          _fcm.redirectToPage(context, message);
        } catch (e) {
          _fcm.showErrorDialog(context, e);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution was what I was looking for, easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a pop-up within the app, then you don't need `onBackgroundMessage` - that is only for processing data when a message is received in the background. There is no way to launch the app at the moment the message is  received.

However, if a user taps on the notification, the app will launch, and either the onResume or onLaunch callbacks will be called.

You can notify the relevant screen to show a pop up when this happens.

Here's a simple implementation:

In `firebase_notification_receiver.dart`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class NotificationEvent {
  final Map<String, dynamic> content;

  /// whether the notification was delivered while the app was in the foreground
  final bool inApp;

  NotificationEvent({this.content, this.inApp = false});
}

class FirebaseNotificationReceiver extends NotificationReceiver {

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  StreamController<NotificationEvent> _controller = StreamController<NotificationEvent>.broadcast();

  StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  Function(NotificationEvent) _listener;

  init{

    // add the rest of the code to initialise firebase here

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(

      /// Fires when App was in foreground when receiving the notification
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        _controller.sink.add(NotificationEvent(content: message, inApp: true));
      },

      /// Fires when App was in background when receiving the notification and user has tapped on it
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _controller.sink.add(NotificationEvent(content: message));
      }

      /// Fires when App was closed when receiving the notification and user has tapped on it
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _controller.sink.add(NotificationEvent(content: message));
      },
    );
    _streamSubscription =
            _controller.stream.listen(_onStreamEvent, onError: (e) {
      print("Notification Stream error $e");
    });
  }

  setListener(Function(NotificationEvent) onData) {
    this._listener = onData;
  }
}
```

In `main.dart`:

```dart
    // imports go here

    void main(){
       final notificationReceiver = NotificationReceiver.firebase();

      runApp(
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            Provider<NotificationReceiver>(
                builder: (_) => notificationReceiver),
            // more providers go here
          ],
          child: App(), // Your custom app class
        ),
      );

    }
```

In `notification_listenable.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class NotificationListenable extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget child;
  final Function(NotificationEvent) onData;

  const NotificationListenable({@required this.child, this.onData});

  @override
  _NotificationListenableState createState() => _NotificationListenableState();
}

class _NotificationListenableState extends State<NotificationListenable> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<NotificationReceiver>(context).setListener(widget.onData);
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

In my_screen.dart:

```dart
/// add your imports here

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _onNotification(NotificationEvent n) {
    (_scaffoldKey.currentState)?.showSnackBar(
       SnackBar(
         duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
         content: Text("I am a pop up"),
       ),
    ),
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return NotificationListenable(
    child: YourCustomScreenContent(),
    onData: _onNotification,
  );
}
```

Comment: Hei, the game changed element of your answer is that i cannot open the app when i receive a message in background, so I just have to "store" the event and present to the user when the app is started (or comes to foreground again). Is this true ?

Also, I like your approach of the listener that handles the notifications. Thanks !

Comment: Basically i need to achieve the following: user receives a notification with a question; i'd like the user to have the chance to click on yes/no, nothing more that this. Like it happens for WhatsApp notifications, that gives you the chance to make a quick reply without opening the application.

With this given, if the standard notifications can be overridden, maybe i can achieve this with them; otherwise i need data messages, that require explicit logic. 

But, about background notifications, my question is: since i'd need to test this when the app si closed, how can i debug this ?

Comment: Ah - you mean rich notifications? It sounds like you need to write those notifications -  in native code, i.e. in Swift / ObjC for iOS or Java/Kotlin for Android. I don't think there is a way of doing that through dart/flutter widgets, unless there is a third-party library that does this.